# Linear operator $X \to X$ with dim $X= \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $T : X \to X$ linear operator where dim $X = \infty$. There exists $S \subseteq  X$ subspace such that $Ker(T) \oplus S = X$ so dim $X = $ dim $Ker(T) +$ dim $S$  and $T|_{S}: S \to X$  is injective, hence $T|_{S} : S \to R(T)$ is linear bijection, and we have that $dim S = dim R(T)$.

Now, suppose that $T$ is injective, so $dim Ker(T) = 0$  and dim $S =$ dim $X =$ dim  $R(T)$. But $R(T)$ is subspace of $X$ and  dim $X =$ dim  $R(T)$, so $X= R(T)$. So $T$ is surjective.

But it's false. Because if you take $f: \mathbb{R}^{\infty} \to  \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ given by $f(a_{1},a_{2},...) = (0,a_{1},a_{2},...)$ is injective, but it is not surjective.

Where am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite dimensional subspace $E$ of an infinite dimensional vector space $F$ is not necessarily equal to $F$. So $dim R(T) =dim X$ does not implies that $R(T)=X$.

Comment: Hi, it looks correct to me, but I'm not conviced about that. Thanks

Comment: Take the space $F$ generated by $e_n, n\geq 0$ and the subspace $E$ generated by $e_n, n\geq 1$, $E$ and $F$ are both infinite dimensional but $E$ is different of $F$ since $e_0$ is not in  $E$.